# Show Quantity as Item in Cart

Tags: magento2.3, cart, onepage-checkout, quantity

I would like to display total quantity of items in cart in the minicart. Basically, we sell items in multiple quantities inside a box, if a user adds 1 box, technically they are adding 10 items. 1 box holds 10 items in it. When I look at checkout and header cart dropdown, it shows as 1 item in cart, however I want it to show me quantity count in cart. I want it to show me the total quantity instead of total item.

For Example :

Item 1 : Qty 10

Item 2 : Qty 20

so currently is showing 2 items in mini cart
but i want show number of product quantity in mini cart

so it should show 30 Qty in mini cart

Thanks in advance

Here's a screenshot of what I meant

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Magento by default provide this.

You need to go to Admin -> Store -> Configuration -> Sales -> Checkout-> My Cart Link

Where you can find Field called **Display Cart Summary** Where you need to select **Display number of items in cart** option

This will show number of items in cart not QTY.

[image]

Comment: I went ahead and updated my question above, seems like it needed more clarification from my end.